# Very indeterminate form: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} -\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)^x \longrightarrow (\infty-\infty)^{\infty}$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, alternative-proof, limits-without-lhopital

Here is problem:

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} -\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)^x$$

The solution I presented in the picture below was made by a [Mathematics Teacher](https://youtu.be/fMCWdiePpb4)

[image]

I tried to solve this Limit without using derivative (L'hospital) and Big O notation. Although I get the answer, I don't know if the technique I'm using definitely correct.

And here is my method:

$$\begin{align*}\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} -\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)^x&=\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac {2x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} +\sqrt{x^2+3}}\right)^x\\&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{ \left(\frac {\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} +\sqrt{x^2+3}}{2x}\right)^x}\end{align*}$$

Then, I define a new function here

$$y(x)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} +\sqrt{x^2+3}-2x-1$$

We have

$$\begin{align*}
\lim _{x\to\infty} y(x)&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} +\sqrt{x^2+3}-2x-1\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}-(x+1))+(\sqrt{x^2+3}-x)\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+x+1}+ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2+3}+x}\\
&=0. 
\end{align*}$$

This implies that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}=\infty $$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{ \left(\frac {\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} +\sqrt{x^2+3}}{2x}\right)^x}&=\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{1}{ \left(\frac{y(x)+2x+1}{2x} \right)^x}\\
&=\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{1}{ \left(1+\frac{y(x)+1}{2x} \right)^x}\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{\left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}}\right)^{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}}\right)^{\frac{y(x)+1}{2}}}\\
&
\end{align*}$$

Here, we define two functions:
$$f(x)=\left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}}\right)^{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}},\quad
g(x)=\frac{y(x)+1}{2}.
$$

We deduce that,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=e>0,\quad \lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=\frac 12>0.
$$
Thus, the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)^{g(x)} $ exists and is finite.

> Finally we get,
>
> $$\begin{align*} 
> \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{\left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}}\right)^{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}}\right)^{\frac{y(x)+1}{2}}}
> &=\frac{1}{\lim_{x \to \infty}\left( \left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}}\right)^{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}}\right)^{\frac{y(x)+1}{2}}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\left(\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}} \right)^{\frac{2x}{y(x)+1}}\right)^{ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{y(x)+1}{2}}}\\ 
> &=\frac {1}{e^{\frac12}}=\frac{\sqrt e}{e}.\\&&
> \end{align*}$$

Is the method I use correct?

I have received criticisms against my work. What can I do to make the method I use, rigorous? What are the points I missed in the method?

Thank you!

Comment: @DMcMor Thank you for edit my bad $\LaTeX$

Comment: Honestly your TeX was pretty good!  I just aligned the equations to make it a bit easier to see.

Comment: Is that who I think it is who did that exposition on the blackboard? :g:

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Nah, it can't be cause there's blue pen ;)

Comment: I'm also a BlackPenRedPen fan! (or is it BlackPenRedPenBluePen?)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire https://youtu.be/fMCWdiePpb4 :)

Comment: @TobyMak I added link to my Question :)

Comment: I don't have enough Latex information to properly align the last lines. I'm sorry..

Comment: @Student look up the align* environment for LaTeX for info on how to align equations, that's what I used to line up the rest in my original edit.

Comment: @DMcMor I got a lot of criticism. That's why I had to edit it...

Comment: $x^y$ is continuous near $\left(e,\frac12\right)$; thus, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)}$ when $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=e$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\frac12$

Comment: @robjohn This is the non-rigorous only point.  As I understand it?

Comment: No. By using the fact that $x^y$ is continuous at this point, it makes your argument rigorous.

Comment: The proper answer depends on what background is available. Using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), we have $\mathrm{d}\!\left(x^y\right)=x^y\left(\frac yx\,\mathrm{d}x+\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)$, so at $\left(e,\frac12\right)$, we have $\mathrm{d}\!\left(x^y\right)=e^{1/2}\left(\frac 1{2e}\,\mathrm{d}x+\mathrm{d}y\right)$. Thus, if $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$ are small enough, we can make $\mathrm{d}\!\left(x^y\right)$ as small as we want. This uses the derivative of $x^y$ to show that $x^y$ is continuous at $\left(e,\frac12\right)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your math looks good!  I'd maybe just an extra step here and there to make it clear what your doing.  Things like showing that you're multiplying by conjugates and maybe a change of variables, say $$z = \frac{2x}{y(x)+1},$$ near the end so it's a bit clearer where the $e$ comes from.  Otherwise everything looks good!  This is a tricky limit, I really like your solution.

Comment: Your math looks good!...and also the answer :-)

Answer (score 7):

The solution appears to be correct. Just for the sake of sanity, here's a different argument, based on the idea that knowing derivatives is knowing *many* limits.

First, find the limit of the logarithm of the beast, which is best treated also with the substitution $x=1/t$, which makes us trying to find
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{t}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+2t+3t^2}-\sqrt{1+3t^2}}{t}\right)
=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{t}\log\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+2t+3t^2}+\sqrt{1+3t^2}}\right)
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}-\frac{\log\bigl(\sqrt{1+2t+3t^2}+\sqrt{1+3t^2}\,\bigr)-\log2}{t}
$$
which is the negative of the derivative at $0$ of
$$
f(t)=\log\bigl(\sqrt{1+2t+3t^2}+\sqrt{1+3t^2}\,\bigr)
$$
Since
$$
f'(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2t+3t^2}+\sqrt{1+3t^2}}\left(\frac{1+3t}{\sqrt{1+2t+3t^2}}+\frac{3t}{\sqrt{1+3t^2}}\right)
$$
we have $f'(0)=1/2$ and therefore the limit is $-1/2$, so your given limit
$$
e^{-1/2}
$$

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is correct but its presentation / application is more complicated than needed here.

Here is how you can use the same approach with much less effort. You have already observed that the base $$F(x) =\sqrt {x^2+2x+3}-\sqrt{x^2+3}$$ tends to $1$ as $x\to\infty $. Now the expression under limit can be written as $$\{F(x) \} ^x=\{\{1+(F(x)-1)\}^{1/(F(x)-1)}\}^{x(F(x)-1)}$$ The inner expression tends to $e$ and the exponent $x(F(x) - 1)\to -1/2$ so that the desired limit is $e^{-1/2}$.

---

Another part of your approach is that it involves the tricky use of subtracting $2x+1$ from $y(x) $. For those who are experienced in the art of calculus this step is obvious via the approximation $$\sqrt{x^2+2ax+b}\approx x+a$$ but it may appear a bit mysterious for a novice. It is best to either explain this part or remove it altogether as I have done it in my answer.

Also note that your approach uses the following limits / rules (it is not necessary to point them out explicitly unless demanded by some strict examiner) :

- $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$
- If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) =a>0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) =b$ then $\{f(x) \} ^{g(x)} \to a^b$ as $x\to\infty $.

Answer (score 4):

By squaring, we can verify that
$$
x\le\sqrt{x^2+3}\le x\left(1+\frac3{2x^2}\right)\tag1
$$
and
$$
x+1\le\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}\le(x+1)\left(1+\frac1{x(x+1)}\right)\tag2
$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives
$$
2x+1\le\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+\sqrt{x^2+3}\le(2x+1)\left(1+\frac3{2x^2}\right)\tag3
$$
Multiplying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+\sqrt{x^2+3}$ gives
$$
\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}-\sqrt{x^2+3}=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+\sqrt{x^2+3}}\tag4
$$
Bernoulli and cross multiplying yield
$$
1-\frac3{2x}\le\left(1-\frac3{2x^2}\right)^x\le\left(1+\frac3{2x^2}\right)^{-x}\tag5
$$
Therefore $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ yield
$$
\left(\frac{2x}{2x+1}\right)^x\left(1-\frac3{2x}\right)\le\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}-\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)^x\le\left(\frac{2x}{2x+1}\right)^x\tag6
$$
The Squeeze Theorem then says
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}-\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)^x=e^{-1/2}\tag7
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct if and only if you truly understand how to rigorously prove a critical step where you effectively claim $\lim_{x∈\mathbb{R}→∞} (1+\frac1x)^{f(x)} = \lim_{x∈\mathbb{R}→∞} e^{f(x)/x}$. Note that this requires real exponentiation, and the simplest proof of this would involve the asymptotic expansions for $\exp,\ln$, hence I personally think it's misleading to think of your method as successfully evading asymptotic expansions. To preempt the very common bogus proof, note that this claim does **not** follow from $\lim_{x∈\mathbb{R}→∞} (1+\frac1x)^x = e$.

After I first posted my answer, you edited your attempt in a non-trivial way. (Please do not edit your question in this way in the future, as it invalidates existing answers.) It still has the same conceptual error, just with different appearance. In this second attempt, you effectively claim that if $\lim_{x∈\mathbb{R}→∞} g(x) = c$ then $\lim_{x∈\mathbb{R}→∞} f(x)^{g(x)} = \lim_{x∈\mathbb{R}→∞} f(x)^c$ if the latter limit exists. This is not in general true! If you can state and prove the correct theorem of this sort (in a comment), then I will believe that you understand it.

The common underlying error is that you replaced part of a limit expression with its limit, which is in general invalid!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92395/discussion-on-answer-by-user21820-very-indeterminate-form-limit-lim-x-to-in).

Comment: "The common underlying error is that you replaced part of a limit expression with its limit, which is in general invalid!" Definitely Wrong argument. Because, all limit rules are *"invalid generally"*. You cannot show the applicable limit rule in all cases.

Comment: @Zaharyas: Your comment makes no sense. I know what I am talking about, and note that the asker deliberately altered the question multiple times after I pointed out the errors, and refused to actually learn proper mathematics. I'm not going to waste more time here.

Comment: Your last sentence is mathematically non sense. (as it appears).

Comment: @Zaharyas: Tell me your mathematical background. If you are willing to learn (unlike the asker), I am willing to teach. But if not, I'm done here.

Comment: I'm IMO gold medalist. Now, I study bachelors.

Comment: @Zaharyas: Since you have IMO background, then you know the difference between logical reasoning and handwaving. Now take a look at [the original question that I answered to](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3185610/2), and you should know what my last sentence refers to. By the way, I am familiar with IMO syllabus, and I know it doesn't include rigorous real analysis, so I still don't know what you know pertaining to this question. Are you familiar with all the rigorous proofs of the standard limit theorems?

Comment: Please give me an example of a clear IMO question (which you don't find rigorous).  ( In recent years). As someone with an adequate background of IMO, I want you to prove your claim.

Comment: @Zaharyas: Are you a native English speaker? If so, why are you putting words into my mouth? Where did I say that IMO questions are not rigorous? Do you recognize the term "real analysis"? Do you know the standard limit theorems?

Comment: IMO does not contain calculus or limit theorems.  The content ranges from extremely difficult algebra and pre-calculus problems to problems on branches of mathematics not conventionally covered at school and often not at university level either, such as projective and complex geometry, functional equations, combinatorics, and well-grounded number theory, of which extensive knowledge of theorems is required.  You asked me about my mathematical background. I gave the answer.

Comment: @Zaharyas: This is the second time you are implicitly putting words into my mouth. I have been teaching for a long time, and I can easily identify when a student has a conceptual error, such as here. You apparently can't. It is not about stating but knowing exactly what assumptions or theorems are used at every step. The asker here **failed** to demonstrate such knowledge, as is evident from the thinking that he/she has successfully evading asymptotic expansions, as adequately explained in my first paragraph. To emphasize, it is like sweeping the dirt under the carpet and claiming it's gone.

Comment: I think there is no "conceptual error" in the old version of the problem. Because, we can see clearly $e^{y(x)+1}$ is not an indeterminate form. If the result was equal, $e^{\infty}$. We can say this is indeterminate. But, $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{y(x)+1}$ is a finite positive number. This is not the only reference.

Comment: @Zaharyas: You "think". How many students have you actually taught real analysis to? And you didn't even address my last two sentences in my last comment above...

Comment: In the old version, only the limit rule is not applied correctly. What is Conceptual error? This is a fixable/solvable error, which is OP fixed it.  Fixable error is not a conceptual error.

Comment: @Zaharyas: Sorry, but there's no point continuing, since you refuse to answer my last three questions.

Answer (score 1):

The proof can be accelerated, using binomial Maclaurin series in the form of
$$\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} = (x+1)\sqrt{1+\dfrac2{(x+1)^2}} = (x+1)\left(1 + \dfrac1{(x+1)^2}+O\left(x^{-4}\right)\right)$$
$$ = x+1+\dfrac1x+O\left(x^{-2}\right),$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+3} = x\left(1+\dfrac3{2x^2}+O(x^{-4})\right) = x + \dfrac3{2x}+O(x^{-3}).$$
Then 
$$\ln L = \ln \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}-\sqrt{x^2+3}\right)^x 
= \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x\ln\left(1-\frac1{2x}+O\left(x^{-2}\right)\right)$$
$$= \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x\left(-\frac1{2x}+O\left(x^{-2}\right)\right) = -\frac12,$$
$$L=e^{\Large^{-\frac12}}.$$